# What's the Python equivalent to C#'s ContinueWith()

Tags: python, python-asyncio

What's the Python equivalent of this code?

```
var firstTask = new Task(() => Foo());
var secondTask = firstTask.ContinueWith((fooResult) => Bar(fooResult));
firstTask.Start();
```

I assume that it'd use the asyncio library.  I know how to create a task in Python, but I can't find a simple example of something that does the same thing as C#'s ContinueWith()

Comment: It is not recommended to use the Task constructor as the Task.Run method should be used to instantiate and start a task (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321321(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Is `Bar` an async function or a regular one?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [`Future.add_done_callback()` callback registration function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.Future.add_done_callback) to do the same; echoing the lambda function support would be:

```
import asyncio

def continue_task_with(task, callback, *, loop=None):
    """When a task completes, schedule a new task.

    The new task is created by calling the callback with the result of
    the first task.

    """
    def done_callback(fut):
        asyncio.ensure_future(callback(fut), loop=loop)
    task.add_done_callback(done_callback)

foo_task = asyncio.ensure_future(foo())
continue_task_with(foo_task, lambda result: bar(result))
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

So this:

- Creates a task for `Foo()`
- Registers a callback on this to be called when the task is done.
- The callback receives the task object, and passes that task object as the first argument to a lambda that creates a `Bar()` coroutine from this. The result of the lambda is then scheduled as a new task to be run.
- Then schedules the `Foo()` task; when that task completes the `Bar()` callback is called to run `Bar()`.

Demo:

```
>>> async def foo():
...     print('Running foo')
...     await asyncio.sleep(1)
...     print('Completing foo')
...     return 42
...
>>> async def bar(foo_task):
...     print('Running bar')
...     if not (foo_task.cancelled() or foo_task.exception()):
...         print('Foo completed successfully, it received', foo_task.result())
...     asyncio.get_event_loop().stop()
...
>>> foo_task = asyncio.ensure_future(foo())
>>> continue_task_with(foo_task, lambda result: bar(result))
>>> asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
Running foo
Completing foo
Running bar
Foo completed successfully, it received 42
```

Comment: What does “task is done” mean? ContinueWith (without further parameters) not only gets executed if the task completes successfully, but also if the task raises an exception or gets cancelled.

Comment: @ckuri That sounds exactly equivalent to [`add_done_callback`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.Future.add_done_callback).

Comment: @user4815162342 I see, according to your link "Done means either that a result / exception are available, or that the future was cancelled."

Comment: @ckuri: `add_done_callback()` is called when the task has *ended*, which can mean a successful completion, or an exception, or the task is cancelled. Calling `.result()` on a task that was cancelled or had an exception raised results in an exception, so the callback fails at that point.

Comment: @ckuri: I've updated the function to pass along the task in its entirety, rather than just the `.result()` return value. I didn't realise that this is what the C# version does anyway (the `TResult` type had me thrown for a bit).